# Can anyone provide me correct Hanuman Dwadashnaam stotram verses and source of this stotram?

Tags: identification-request, hanuman, stotra, source

Can someone please provide the Hanuman Dwadashnaam stotram verses in sanskrit and the source of this stotram?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

Hanumaan dwadasha Nama stotram is a part of [Ananda Ramayana](https://archive.org/details/HindiBookAnandRamayan) , Manohara Kanda, Sarga 13.
Meaning of which is available on several sites hosting the same.
One of them is [greenmesg](https://greenmesg.org/stotras/hanuman/twelve_names_of_hanuman.php).

> हनुमानञ्जनसूनुर्वायुपुत्रो (Hanumaan-An.janaa-Sunur-Vaayu-Putro): Hanuman Who is the Son of Devi Anjana and Vayu Deva
> हनुमान (Hanumaana) = Hanuman
> अञ्जन (An.jana) = Anjana Devi, the Mother of Hanuman
> सूनु (Suunu) = Son
> वायु (Vaayu) = The Wind God
> पुत्र (Putra) = Son
> महाबलः (Mahaa-Balah): Who has Great Strength
> महा (Mahaa) = Great
> बल (Bala) = Strength
> रामेष्टः (Raama-Issttah): Who is Devoted to Sri Rama
> राम (Raama) = Sri Rama
> इष्ट (Isstta) = Devoted to, Istha Devata
> फाल्गुनसखः (Phaalguna-Sakhah): Who is a Friend of Arjuna
> फाल्गुन (Phaalguna) = Arjuna
> सख (Sakha) = Friend
> पिङ्गाक्षोऽमितविक्रमः (Pingga-Aksso-Amita-Vikramah): Whose Eyes are Brownish [or Yellowish] and Whose Valour is Boundless
> पिङ्ग (Pingga) = Yellow, Reddish Brown
> अक्ष (Akssa) = Eye
> अमित (Amita) = Unmeasured, Boundless
> विक्रम (Vikrama) = Valour, Courage
> उदधिक्रमणश्चैव (Udadhi-Kramannash-Ca-Eva): Who has Crossed the Ocean
> उदधि (Udadhi) = Ocean
> क्रमण (Kramanna) = Stepping, Walking, Crossing
> एव (Eva) = Indeed
> सीताशोकविनाशनः (Siitaa-Shoka-Vinaashanah): Who Removed the Sorrow of Devi Sita
> सीता (Siitaa) = Devi Sita
> शोक (Shoka) = Sorrow
> विनाश (Vinaasha) = Destruction, Annihilation
> लक्ष्मणप्राणदाताश्च (Lakssmanna-Praanna-Daataash-Ca): Who is the Giver of Life to Sri Lakshmana
> लक्ष्मण (Lakssmanna) = Lakshmana
> प्राण (Praanna) = Life
> दाता (Daataa) = Giver
> च (Ca) = And
> दशग्रीवस्य (Dasha-Griivasya): of Ten Necks, referring to Ten-Headed Ravana
> दश (Dasha) = Ten
> ग्रीव (Griiva) = Neck
> दर्पहा (Darpa-Haa): Who Destroyed the Pride of the Ten-Headed Ravana
> दर्प (Darpa) = Pride
> ह (Ha) = Killing, Destroying, Removing
> एवं (Evam): Indeed
> द्वादश (Dvaadasha): Twelve
> नामानि (Naamaani): Names
> नाम (Naama) = Name
> कपीन्द्रस्य (Kapiindrasya): Who is the Best among the Monkeys
> कपी (Kapii) = Monkey
> इन्द्र (Indra) = Best, Excellent
> महात्मनः (Mahaatmanah): Noble
> स्वापकाले (Svaapa-Kaale): During Sleep
> स्वाप (Svaapa) = Sleep
> काल (Kaala) = Time
> प्रबोधे (Prabodhe): After Waking up
> प्रबोध (Prabodha) = Waking
> च (Ca): And
> यात्रा (Yaatraa): Journey
> काले (Kaale): During
> यः (Yah): He who
> पठेत् (Patthet): Recites
> पठ (Pattha) = Reading, Reciting
> तस्य (Tasya): To him
> सर्वभयं (Sarva-Bhayam): All Fears
> सर्व (Sarva) = All
> भय (Bhaya) = Fear
> नास्ति (Na-Asti): Does not Exist
> न (Na) = Not
> अस्ति (Asti) = Existent, Present
> रणे (Ranne): During the Battle
> रण (Ranna) = Battle, War
> विजयी (Vijayii): Victorious
> भवेत् (Bhavet): Becomes
> भव (Bhava) = To Be, to Become
> राजद्वारे (Raaja-Dvaare): In the King's Palace
> राज (Raaja) = King
> द्वार (Dvaara) = Gate
> गह्वरे (Gahvare): In the Cave
> गह्वर (Gahvara) = Cave
> भयं (Bhayam): Fear
> कदाचन (Kadaacana): Any Time
> (*Translation greenmesg.org*)

Comment: What is the chhanda of this stotra?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Hanuman Dwadasha Nama Stotra is an independent work, like many other stotras.

**Hanuman Dwadasa Nama Stotram which is also known as Anjaneya Dwadasa Nama Stotram** is a very vital hymn dedicated to Lord Hanumaana. It is said to make the chanter confident and fearless while facing severe bottle necks in your life.

> ### [Sanskrit Verses](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_hanumaana/Anjaneya12.html)
>
> श्रीआंजनेय द्वादशनामस्तोत्रम् :
>
> हनुमानंजनासूनुः वायुपुत्रो महाबलः । रामेष्टः फल्गुणसखः
> पिंगाक्षोऽमितविक्रमः ॥ १॥
>
> उदधिक्रमणश्चैव सीताशोकविनाशकः । लक्ष्मण प्राणदाताच दशग्रीवस्य दर्पहा ॥
> २॥
>
> द्वादशैतानि नामानि कपींद्रस्य महात्मनः । स्वापकाले पठेन्नित्यं
> यात्राकाले विशेषतः । तस्यमृत्यु भयंनास्ति सर्वत्र विजयी भवेत् ॥
>
> #### IAST Transliteration
>
> śrīāṃjaneya dvādaśanāmastotram :
>
> hanumānaṃjanāsūnuḥ vāyuputro mahābalaḥ । rāmeṣṭaḥ phalguṇasakhaḥ
> piṃgākṣo'mitavikramaḥ ॥ 1॥
>
> udadhikramaṇaścaiva sītāśokavināśakaḥ । lakṣmaṇa prāṇadātāca
> daśagrīvasya darpahā ॥ 2॥
>
> dvādaśaitāni nāmāni kapīṃdrasya mahātmanaḥ । svāpakāle paṭhennityaṃ
> yātrākāle viśeṣataḥ । tasyamṛtyu bhayaṃnāsti sarvatra vijayī bhavet ॥
>
> **English Translation**
>
> > Anjaneya Dwadasanama Stotram [Meaning](https://templesinindiainfo.com/anjaneya-dwadasanama-stotram-lyrics-in-english-with-meaning/):
> >
> > O Hanuman, son of Anjana and Vayu! You possess great strength. Liked
> > by Rama, you are friend of Arjuna, the great warrior of Mahabhaarata.
> > You are brown eyed and a boundless brave personality. Crossing sea,
> > you removed Sita’s grief. You gave life to Laxmana. Driven out pride
> > of ten-headed Ravana.
> >
> > All these are twelve names of the great souled monkey king Hanuman.
> > Whoever recite them daily morning and especially during journeys,
> > There will be no death or fear to him and there will be victory
> > always. Wisdom, strength, fame, courage, fearlessness, no diseases and
> > infections, command over language – he will obtain all these by
> > reciting Hanuman names.

One can access the separate names, known as Hanuman Dwadash Namavali of the same stotra [from here](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_hanumaana/AnjaneyadvAdashanAmAvaliH.html).

---

### Source:

As regards it's source scripture, as I already mentioned, most probably it's an independent work, or part of some non-extant scriptures, currently untraceable.

- At the very best, it's found as the part of *dhyana shloka* 9 & 10,of Chapter 75, 76 of the Bala Kanda of the Valmiki Ramayana, as per the [Sanskritdocuments website](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_raama/chp75_76.html).
- As per [Sanskrit Documents Website](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_vishhnu/vAyu_stuti.html), yet again, it forms the concluding part of the [Vayu-Stuti](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vayu_Stuti), also known as Hari Vayu Stuti, composed by a renowned Madhwa sect scholar Pandit Trivikram.

So mostly, it's either an independent work, or maybe attributed to Pandit Trivikram of the Madhwa sampradaya.

Comment: Nice answer but not satisfied. So waiting for others to give it a try.